# Starting mysql container using docker machine with virtual box shared folder

Tags: mysql, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm trying to create a local dev setup using Docker Machine. I keep running into error when trying to create a mysql container. Here's my setup.

docker-machine version 0.3.0

Virtualbox version 4.3.30

Default boot2docker vm in virtualbox, with shared folder /Users

I created the mysql folder to be mounted on creating the container at `/Users/tinnguyen/Development/Docker/containers/mysql`

Standard permission:

`drwxr-xr-x  2 tinnguyen  staff    68 Jul 25 16:45 mysql`

Below is my docker command

`docker run -d --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -v /Users/tinnguyen/Development/Docker/containers/mysql:/var/lib/mysql mysql`

When I do `docker logs mysql`, this is the error I got

```
docker logs mysql
Running mysql_install_db
2015-07-25 21:45:45 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.25) starting as process 29 ...
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-07-25 21:45:45 7f8c9b939720  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2015-07-25 21:45:45 7f8c9b939720  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [ERROR] InnoDB: Creating or opening ./ibdata1 failed!
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [ERROR] Aborting

2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] Binlog end
2015-07-25 21:45:45 29 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Would really appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: try with a volume which is not under `/Users`

Answer (score 0):

By default, it should be setup correctly and work but you may want to check the folder sharing setting on VirtualBox.

run VirtualBox, check the default machine Settings. Click on Shared Folders and verify that /Users folder from your host macbook is mounted in the VM.